# Cloudformation remove dashes from parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to run a nested stack with the root stack that creates multiple resources including S3 buckets and a Cognito User Pool. The issue is:

- S3 bucket name doesn't allow Capitalised letters.
- Cognito Identity Pool name doesn't allow dashes `-`.

I want to name my resources with the same/similar name `${AWS::StackName}-then-some-string` so they're recognised as parts of one application.

Is there a way to remove dashes from parameters inside cloudformation? I know I can use `Fn::Split` to split the string with `-` then use `Fn::Select` to select specific elements then `Fn::Join` but that will only work for a stack name with a certain amount of dashes `-`.

I can't find any resource anywhere on how to change the `-` to empty string or something else using some sort of function or regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're nearly there - use `Fn::Split` and `Fn::Join`, no select needed.

```
SomeKey:
  Fn::Join:
  - ''
  - Fn::Split:
    - '-'
    - !Ref YourParam
```

`Split` returns an array. `Join` takes a join string and an array of items to join. So just split on the hyphen/dash, then join the parts back together with an empty string, thereby eliminating the hyphens.

Comment: Thank you @404. You're absolutely right! What was I thinking?